# Irreducible unitary representation of $\text{SU}(2)$ and multiplicity of $J_3$ eigenvalues

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, eigenvalue, unitarity

I searched a lot about this, but I can't find anything near to an answer.
I'm trying to find an irreducible unitary representation of $\text{SU}(2)$ Lie group, so writing the generic element as $e^{i\vartheta^j J_j}$, where $\{\vartheta^j\}$ are the $3$ parameters of the group, we immediately find from the unitarity that all $J_j$ are hermitian.

In the hypothesis we are acting on a finite dimensional Hilbert carrier space, we can say that every linear operator on it is limited and compact and in the eventuality it is also hermitian we can apply Hilbert-Schmidt theorem; so for example choosing $J_3$, I could know that its eigenvectors create a basis for the carrier space.

What I don't understand is why these $J_3$ eigenstates, usually referred to as $|m\rangle$, should live is simple eigenspaces; everytime I read something about it, seems like the multiplicity of every $m$ eigenvalue is simply $1$.

Is it true or not? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplicity of the $J_3$ eigenvalues is always $1$ in every irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Irreducible representations of semisimple Lie algebras can be obtained as (quotients of) [Verma modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module). By the [Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) we know that a basis of this space, for the case of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is
$$
(J_-)^{k_-}(J_+)^{k_+}(J_3)^{k_3}\,,\qquad k_-,\,k_+,\,k_3 \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\,.
$$
You can immediately see that, starting from a highest weight element, all the other elements are built by powers of $(J_-)^{k_-}$. Each of them will have a different $J_3$ eigenvalue, and by the theorem cited above, they are all distinct.

Comment: Thank you so much you gave me real relief! That's definitely something I'm not able to prove (sadly we miss a course on group theory in my university and I had to study it alone, not able to arrive at this level of knowledge). So I'm asking also, is there a simpler way to demonstrate it? I was trying the whole morning, initially from the commutation relations of the group (that was a dead end because we don't know the general form of $J_1,J_2$ or similarly $J_+,J_-$), but I soon realized that all was just about the only fact that the representation was irreducible.

Comment: So I tried to consider  for example $e^{i\vartheta^3 J_3}$ and say that if I had an eigenvalue $\tilde{m}$ with two eigenvectors $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$, they would be able to create an irreducible subspace of $e^{i\vartheta^3 J_3}$, meaning that $e^{i\vartheta^3 J_3}(\alpha|a\rangle+\beta|b\rangle)=e^{i\vartheta^3\tilde{m}}(\alpha|a\rangle+\beta|b\rangle)$... But that wasn't helpful, because I can always considers invariant subsets of an irreducible representation $e^{i\vartheta^j J_j}$, so that was a dead end too. Is there a similar way to get to the result?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to continue your attempts to a proof. Perhaps you should look at it in a more algebraic way, rather than trying to construct the representations explicitly.